# How to test fragment retention across configuration changes with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-fragments, robolectric

I would like to know if there is a way to test fragment retention across configuration changes using Roblectric.

I just found out that there is no ShadowFragmentManager.

Comment: You want to be testing your code, not Android.